# Allow other PC to access proxy installed on my laptop, in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, socks-proxy

I've created a ssh proxy to server by invoking this command:

```
ssh -p1234 -D1234 someuser@someserver
```

With this, I'm able to load certain pages from my firefox, however, the one who need to access that particular sites is my colleague. But, they don't have ssh akses to that server.
Now, I want her to be able to access the tunnel which is opened on my laptop. How do I enable that? Because, if I set the proxy on her browser to myip:1234, it's always connection refused!.

TIA.

Comment: Do you have any iptable/firewall rules enabled ?

Comment: no, I don't have both installed.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security issues, ssh -D will only listen on lo0. You must bind to eth0. You could also listen on all NICs by giving -g flag:

```
ssh -g -p1234 -D1234 someuser@someserver
```

but remember this will let ALL people use your PC as proxy :(